# How can I play an audio file embedded in the resource?

Tags: vb.net, audio, embedded-resource

my issue is quite simple:

I incorporated a .wav file in my solution adding an existing element and setting its "Build Action" property on "Embedded Resource". Now I would like to play it. How could I do it?

Comment: You are asking how to play audio in vb?

Comment: The [SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) class located in the `Sytem.Media` namespace might fit you need.

Comment: Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream() + SoundPlayer.Stream.  Do favor using the Resource designer.

Comment: @Error404 How to play audio from an embedded file, exactly.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Yes, I used that and it works now, thank you.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you too, I used:
Dim s As New SoundPlayer
s.Stream=Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("solution_name.file_name.wav")
s.Play()

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you added a wave file called Music.wav to project resources. Try like this

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Music)
```

This should work :)